# AWS batch cannot run fargate container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-batch

I have created aws batch job using fargate computed environment. But when I submit the job it is failing. AWS Batch is created the Fargate task but it is failing to run the container. But when I run fargate task manually. It is running. Here is cloudwatch log after running manually the fargate task

[image: Fargate batch task run manually]

Answer (score 0):

Configure Job attempt while submitting the job. Now batch job is running